# node-master: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node-master: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

i have a problem about starting the namenode, i have delete the node-master i have config in the host file but my name node still use it to run
Here is the error

```
start-dfs.sh
23/12/25 17:51:36 WARN hdfs.DFSUtilClient: Namenode for null remains unresolved for ID null. Check your hdfs-site.xml file to ensure namenodes are configured properly.
Starting namenodes on [node-master]
node-master: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node-master: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Here is my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       dell-Inspiron-3593
#HDFS
#127.0.0.1 node-master
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1       kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Here is my hdfs-site.xml file, i have modify the the localhost in dfs.namenode.http-address

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hdoop/dfsdata/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hdoop/dfsdata/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9870</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9864</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

i have tried restart delete tmp folder and dfsdata folder and restart but it stills do not work. And i have tried ping the node-master , it do not exists

```
ping: node-master: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: 1) The error comes from the core-site.xml, not hdfs-site.xml 2) `#127.0.0.1 node-master` - this line has a comment. Uncomment if you want that hostname to be resolved... Also, the hadoop-aws documentation says to remove all lines that start with `127.0.1.1` 3) You don't need to use start-dfs to start the namenode

Comment: thank u so much , i have found the problem in the core-site.xml file, and i have fixed by change the node-master to localhost. But there is a new problem that when i use start-dfs.sh , my secondary name node don't start although my name node and data node work normally

Comment: Not sure. You'll need to check the logs